# Android Studio basic project - error on compilation - com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException failed to run comand ...\dx.bat

Tags: java, android, batch-file, compiler-errors

Hy everyone. I've started to learn android development. I watched this tutorial( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mPnOgqZhK_o&index=6&list=PL_PaSTBkUwk4PXlhZIe4COpwnWeCRnw2F ) and i have written same code, but i get this errors when i try to compile and run this project:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexRelease'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       C:\Users\Gabi\Desktop\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\build-tools\android-4.4W\dx.bat --dex --output C:\Users\Gabi\AndroidStudioProjects\ContactManager\app\build\intermediates\dex\release C:\Users\Gabi\AndroidStudioProjects\ContactManager\app\build\intermediates\classes\release
>   Error Code:
>       1
>   Output:
>       The system cannot find the path specified.

I don't know how to resolve this... please help me